# how to configure ApacheSolr with spring mvc?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, solr

I am using Spring MVC for my project and would like to use Apache Solr to perform the database search. Could anybody guide me how to configure Apche Solr with Spring or can i use hibernate search? or any better approach.

Thanks & Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used Hibernate search so can't comment but I have written a number of Spring MVC webapps that use SOLR.

There are quite a few ways to integrate SOLR...

- You could run a stand alone instance of SOLR and then use an [AJAX approach](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr) to build your search pages.
- You could write a simple Java `Service` that calls SOLR via its REST web service interface (e.g., using Spring's [`RestTemplate`](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/) - JSON output is easier to marshall).
- Or you could use a more native approach and implement a Service/DAO using [SolrJ](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj).

I've used the last two approaches mentioned... Webservices is slightly easier to get up and running but SolrJ is more powerful. I've also used the embedded SOLR with SolrJ which simplifies deployment as there is only a single war file to deploy and manage.

Comment: @nicjdos I like your second approach could you post some sample code?

Comment: Re-reading your Q, I relaise you are asking about adding fulltext search to an existing relational database. SOLR is a lot of work to do this, Hibernate search is a much simpler solution in this case. In my case we had a custom SOLR indexer that indexed many kinds of documents (not RDBS backed).